# Jquery Ajax request to Sinatra app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ajax, sinatra

I've been at this for a while, but am missing something. I've just set up a simple Sinatra app returning JSON:

```
get '/json' do
  content_type :json
  $data.to_json
end
```

This is working fine, and then the javascript I'm using to do a cross domain request is

```
$.getJSON("http://domain.com/json?callback=?", function(data) {
   console.log(data);
});
```

Unfortunately with this I just keep getting the error in the console `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` and although I've tried a just using the `$.ajax` method instead, I still get the same result.

Is this an error on my server or client side code? any help appreciated.

Comment: $data is a hash compiling values from a couple of different sources.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant, where do you get this error? :)

Comment: through the console in Chrome

Comment: I think this is an error on the server side. There must be something wrong with the json. Also you can check if using callback without arguments will throw the error also. It should not. There must be something wrong with the hash.

Comment: a useful thing when having problems with json is to run the returned json through any of the json lint thingies on the web. (google "json lint")

Comment: Aaron, When you go to `/json` just using your browser, does the result look like valid json? As froderik mentioned above, run it through json lint will help show you if the json is correct: http://jsonlint.com/. If the json is correct, it's likely javascript side, if it's not, it's server side.

Comment: OK, seems the JSON is valid. looks like it the JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned you are making a cross domain request. For JSONP, you need to wrap your json response to mimic a function call. There is a [Sinatra helper](http://podtynnyi.com/2010/05/28/sinatra-jsonp-output-helper/) which makes it easy.

Comment: thanks kxb. Thought I wouldn't need a 3rd party lib, but this did the trick.

Comment: Just a note on this. Although it works, the retuned data is a sting, and needs to be then converted into a JSON object with `data: jQuery.parseJSON(data)` in order to be used within other functions.

Answer (score 1):

**Here working example with different port**

Ruby with Sinatra

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require "sinatra/jsonp"

get '/note/all/' do
  data = ["hello","hi","hallo"]
  JSONP data      # JSONP is an alias for jsonp method
End
```

HTML hosted on apache

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title> English </title>
    <link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // to update alternative address
        $('#Updateprofile').click(function () {
        var key = "nickname"
            var details = $('#nickname').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:4567/note/all/',
            crossDomain: true,
            data: '',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('#controlstatus').html(+responseData);
            },
            error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('POST failed.'+textStatus);
            }
        });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="mstform" method="post" runat="server">
<input id="nickname" type="text" style="border: thin solid #C0C0C0; background-color: #EFEFEF;
        width: 300px;" />
   <br />
    <br />
    <img alt="update" id="Updateprofile" src="images/save.png" title="Clicking this button will update your profile" />
   <br />
    <br />
<div id="controlstatus"> details should be here
</div>
    </form>
</body>
```